# Can I bake a single rigid body and repeat it?

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, instances

[image]
I am attempting to make a production line of boxes proceeding down a roller conveyor. Because the action is so repetitive, I would like to bake one instance of the physics, and translate the other instances by time, or by X-axis. I understand the system looks simple, but it gets more complicated in my larger assembly.

Comment: Once you've baked the action, you can use the NonLinear animation window to offset the action of each box if there are a lot, i guess it's also doable with geometry nodes?

Comment: I am trying it now.

Comment: Ok that is the answer. Thanks! post it as an answer

Comment: Wait, how do I give a new instance the 'action'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've baked the simulation, go into the *Dope Sheet*, switch it to *Action Editor*, give the action a name, push it down into the *Nonlinear Animation* window:

[image]

The action has disappeared from the *Dope Sheet* but it is now available as a yellow strip in the *Nonlinear Animation* window, you can move this strip if you want to offset the action:

[image]

Now duplicate your cube object, select the action again in the *Dope Sheet* dropdown menu in order to assign it to this second cube, and again push down the action, or select your copy, shift select the original and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Animation Data* (which will automatically create a second strip in the NLA):

[image]

Now that you have a second strip in the NLA, move it to the right in order to offset the action:

[image]